# Drawing a grid in javascript ( game of life, for example )

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, cellular-automata

Essentially, I had this idea in my head for a sort of evolution simulator, not exactly like Conways Game of Life, but the one part where they do match is that they will both be based on a square grid.

Now, personally, I like working in HTML+Javascript+ for simple apps, since it allows fast UI creation, and if you're not doing something computationally heavy, then JS in a browser is a decent platform.

The problem I'm trying to solve right now involves drawing and updating the grid. I might be missing something, but it seems like there is no easy AND computationally light way of doing this for an 80x40 grid. The easy way would be to generate a div with absolute position and a specific background color for any square that is NOT empty. However that can become very slow with anything more than 60-70 colored squares.

I'm definitely willing to switch to a different language if the situation calls for it, but first I just want to know I'm not stupidly missing out on an easy way to do this with HTML+JS.

Answer should include either one of the following:

a) A reasonable way to draw and update a 80x40 grid ( where the squares change color and "move" ) in HTML+JS

b) Another language that can do this reasonably fast. I would prefer to avoid having to spend a few days learning DirectDraw or something of the sort.

Comment: Have you tried using a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not build the grid as an HTML Table? After all this is what you want?

Give each cell a computed id and create some javascript functions to update them. Shoudlnt be a problem at all.

You could look at the new canvas tag in HTML 5 but from what you've said I dont think you need it.

Comment: I haven't tried the computed table yet, but I figured that having to process 80x40 <td></td> would be more work than processing the divs for only the colored squares. My browser slowed down on generating my test grid of only half the squares being colored, so I don't know whether it can handle that many table cells.

Comment: Never mind. Tried using a table and for some reason, even though there's more HTML being generated, it worked faster. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

[`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_graphics_with_canvas) seems to be the right way to do this. A library like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) will help you avoid cross-platform issues. Another options is [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/), but it does not work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

For a small grid (< 100x100), use a table and give each cell an ID for fast access.

For bigger grids, you should consider using a canvas object or embedding an Java or Flash applet.